# Unable to add magento-ecg/coding-standard to PHP_CodeSniffer:

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

Unable to install `magento-ecg/coding-standard` to `PHP_CodeSniffer`:
Tried below command after cloning PHP_CodeSniffer from github:

`phpcs --config-set installed_paths ./vendor/magento-ecg/coding-standard`

But phpcs -i is showing only following standards.

> The installed coding standards are PSR1, MySource, Zend, Squiz, PHPCS,
>   PEAR and PSR2

Comment: If you have a possibility try to put it in default path and see if it works:
`/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/`



Another thing you can try is using full path to standards directory:
`phpcs --config-set installed_paths /home/your_user/vendor/magento-ecg/coding-standard`

Answer (score 9):

facing the same problem solved it by

**git clone https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard**

then added the complete path where you clone it

**phpcs --config-set installed_paths /home/your_user/vendor/magento-ecg/coding-standard**

End reuslt
**phpcs -i**

**The installed coding standards are PSR1, PSR2, PEAR, MySource, PHPCS, Zend, Squiz, Ecg and EcgM2**

Comment: I have taken clone in my magento 2 folder.  
for below command what will be the installed_paths?  Also  what will be /home/your_user/vendor/magento-ecg/coding-standard?
phpcs --config-set installed_paths /home/your_user/vendor/magento-ecg/coding-standard

Comment: @jack which folder your standard is located that will be installed path

Answer (score 0):

i followed below steps in windows local system 
first installed xammp

1. cd C:\xampp\php
2. pear install PHP_CodeSniffer
      pear install --alldeps PHP_CodeSniffer

(if there is any issue run cmd as Administrator)

[image]

phpcs -i

3. then to follow Magento coding install  magento-ecg/coding-standard from composer
4. after install it will be in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento217\vendor\magento-ecg\
5. now run  (C:\xampp\php>)

   phpcs --config-set installed_paths C:\xampp\htdocs\magento217\vendor\magento-ecg\coding-standard

now it will have all plugins need for M2

phpcs -i

**The installed coding standards are PSR1, PSR2, PEAR, MySource, PHPCS, Zend, Squiz, Ecg and EcgM2**

To test Module run below code

```
C:\xampp\php>phpcs C:\xampp\htdocs\magento217\app\code\NAMESPACE\MODULE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Magento coding standard using following approach

1. `composer require --dev magento/magento-coding-standard`

when installed this way the Magento standard for phpcs cannot be added automatically. You can achieve this by adding the following to your project's composer.json

2.

```
 "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/)"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/)"
    ]
}
```

For more information check https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard